# How to account for two different types of strings when using preg_match?

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I need help modifying the regex that is being used as the pattern in preg_match to account for both types of strings, one with the last name, and one without the last name.

```
$string = "Tim Johnson (M) - 12/19/2001 (14 years)";

$re = '~^(?<fname>[\p{L}-]+)\h+(?<lname>[\p{L}\h-]+?)\h+\((?<gender>[MF])\)[-\h]+(?<dob>[\d/]+)~mu';

preg_match($re, $string, $matches);
```

will return an array of:

```
array(
  'fname'  => 'Tim',
  'lname'  => 'Johnson',
  'gender' => 'M',
  'dob'    => '12/29/2001',
)
```

But if the string is (missing the last name):

```
$string = "Tim (M) - 12/19/2001 (14 years)";
```

It will return an array of:

```
array(
  'fname'  => '',
  'lname'  => '',
  'gender' => 'M',
  'dob'    => '',
)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use an optional non-capturing group around `\h+(?<lname>[\p{L}\h-]+?)` pattern:

```
^(?<fname>[\p{L}-]+)(?:\h+(?<lname>[\p{L}\h-]+?))?\h+\((?<gender>[MF])\)[-\h]+(?<dob>[\d/]+)
                    ^^^                         ^^
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/T5w1oO/1)

The `(?:...)?` is a non-capturing group that has a `?` quantifier applied to it, it makes the sequence of patterns inside it match 1 or 0 times, i.e. makes them optional *as a sequence*.